# Button click not returning result to textview

Tags: android, android-button

I'm new to coding and a little iffy with my knowledge so forgive me if I've overlooked something simple, but I've been searching for 2 hours for an answer.

One of my classes is going to allow a user to input their height and weight, and return the BMI (Body Mass Index) for them. The problem is once they click on the button that performs the calculation and displays it in a TextView, nothing happens. The only error I see from LogCat is `getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection`. This error only shows when I use the `next` button on the `softkeyboard` to move between EditText fields, so I don't believe this is related, as there is still no result when I manually move between fields and don't get this error. Feel free to assist with this issue too though, if you have any info.

This is duplicate code from a BMI android developing tutorial, word for word except for the id's of the items, but the tutorial works perfectly when loaded into the emulator. My code is as follows:

```
public class FuncConverter extends DashMenuActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.dash_converter7);

    Spinner converter_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.converter_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> converter_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.converter_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    converter_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        converter_spinner.setAdapter(converter_adapter);

}


public void calcClick (View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.convert_btn_calc) {

        EditText weight_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_edit);
        EditText height_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_edit);
        TextView bmi_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_text);

        float weight = Float.parseFloat(weight_edit.getText().toString());
        float height = Float.parseFloat(height_edit.getText().toString());

        float bmiValue = calculateBMI (weight, height);
        String bmiCalc = interpretBMI (bmiValue);

        bmi_text.setText(bmiValue + " - " + bmiCalc); 

    }

}


private float calculateBMI (float weight, float height) {
    return (float) (weight / (height * height));
}

private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {
    if (bmiValue < 16) {
        return "Severley Underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 18.5) {
        return "Underweight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 25) {
        return "Healthy weight";
    } else if (bmiValue < 30) {
        return "Overweight";
    } else {
        return "Obese";
    }
}}
```

Comment: What is triggering the action to return the BMI as a TextView? Like is `calcClick` defined as a `onClick` in the xml?

Comment: I'm using Andy's method for this now, but it turned out I had overlooked a mistake in my XML, by putting `onClick="calcClick"` instead of `android:onClick="calcClick"`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just remember, almost everything if not everything starts with `android:` in xml for the attributes of the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really hard for me to answer definitively because I am not sure how you are triggering the click to calculate the stuff. But from what i can tell `calcClick(View)` is defined as `onClick=calcClick` in your xml. If this is true then you are getting the information the wrong way.

```
public class FuncConverter extends DashMenuActivity {
EditText weight_edit;
EditText height_edit;
TextView bmi_text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.dash_converter7);

    Spinner converter_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.converter_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> converter_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.converter_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    converter_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    converter_spinner.setAdapter(converter_adapter);

    //Moved these bad boys here for you instead
    weight_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_edit);
    height_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_edit);
    bmi_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_text);

}


public void calcClick (View view) {

if (view.getId() == R.id.convert_btn_calc) { //dont't think you need this check to be honest



    float weight = Float.parseFloat(weight_edit.getText().toString());
    float height = Float.parseFloat(height_edit.getText().toString());

    float bmiValue = calculateBMI (weight, height);
    String bmiCalc = interpretBMI (bmiValue);

    bmi_text.setText(bmiValue + " - " + bmiCalc); 

    }

}
```

What I did there was just move the `EditText` and `TextView` as globals so then you have access to it in `calcClick(View)`. If I am right , the reason it wasn't working is because you don't have access to the `EditText` and `TextView` views from the xml outside of `onCreate()`, at least in your case. What that `View` argument is that is getting passed is actually the button or whatever is triggering the event. Hopefully that makes sense. So `View view` isn't the document root but rather `(Button)view` or again, whatever you are clicking to trigger this.

Comment: Your method still returned the same results, but of course it was something I overlooked. my xml had `onClick="calcClick"` instead of `android:onClick="calcClick"`